# Why can't i copy files to my NAS?

Tags: networking, file-sharing, nas

I can normally access all of my NAS shares without issue from my Ubuntu laptop.  I have bookmarked all of the shares without issue, although they are a little slow to access.

However moving files to and from the NAS is driving me crazy!!!  I can play music files, and movies, but i can't select them to copy.

Most annoying is that it is impossible to copy a folder/ file from my laptop to the NAS, every time i get the following error;

The specified location is not mounted

I then try again to find that the folder has been copied, but only part of the contents.

Does anyone have a suggestion what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

did you try:

----- NFS mounten
 mount -t nfs 192.168.0.100:/mnt/IDE1/nas /mnt/nfs -o rw,nolock,intr,soft,udp,rsize=4096,wsize=4096

----- Cifs mounten
 mount -t cifs //192.168.0.20/video /mnt/nfs/ -o user=harry,passwort=hase